# list of wx.ICON_ options in wxpython

Tags: python, icons, wxpython

I am having difficulty finding a list of all of the inbuilt icons in wxpython.

So far I have found

```
wx.ICON_INFORMATION
wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION
```

If you knew of such a list, it would be much appreciated. Alternatively please leave any that have not been included.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How beautiful is python introspection:

```
>>> import wx
>>> mod = dir(wx)
>>> [item for item in mod if item.startswith('ICON_')]
['ICON_ASTERISK', 'ICON_ERROR', 'ICON_EXCLAMATION', 'ICON_HAND', 
 'ICON_INFORMATION', 'ICON_MASK', 'ICON_QUESTION', 'ICON_STOP', 'ICON_WARNING']
>>>
```